# How can I fix terraform alpine installation package?

Tags: jenkins, terraform, alpine-linux

Currently I'm using my personal build Dockerimage to deploy my terraform code with Jenkins. The docker images looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG GLIBC_VERSION=2.35-r0
ARG AWSCLI_VERSION=2.11.11

RUN apk update

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache --force-overwrite \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && ln -sf /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-${AWSCLI_VERSION}.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/examples \
        glibc-*.apk \
    && find /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/botocore/data -name examples-1.json -delete \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add terraform --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community
```

Since today the command  `RUN apk add terraform --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable` is not working anymore, as APKINDEX.tar.gz file can't be found by the system. I saw that there was an update on the terraform package site today. The error that I'm getting now is the following:

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
[91mERROR: unable to select packages:
  terraform (no such package):
    required by: world[terraform]
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c apk add terraform --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Does anyone know, what the problem is that I'm running into and how can I fix this?

Comment: I think terraform was removed from the Alpine repositories due to the licensing issue. So you could probably solve it by downloading the zip file, extracting it and moving it to the bin directory of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by Marko E in the comments, the liscence model of terraform changed today. To be still able to use this Dockerimage as a Jenkins agent for deploying terraform code via pipeline, I changed the image to the following:

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER Leon

ARG GLIBC_VERSION=2.35-r0
ARG AWSCLI_VERSION=2.11.11
ARG TERRAFORM_VERSION=1.6.6

RUN apk update

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache --force-overwrite \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && ln -sf /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-${AWSCLI_VERSION}.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/examples \
        glibc-*.apk \
    && find /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/botocore/data -name examples-1.json -delete \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


RUN apk --no-cache add curl unzip

RUN curl -LO https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip \
    && unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin \
    && rm terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip

RUN terraform --version
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).